# Datepicker required option working but readonly not working?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, datepicker

I have a date picker with following `HTML` code :

```
<input id="datepicker3" name="date" type="text" placeholder="Booking Date" class="date" required>
```

It will show required field alert when tried to submit the form without filling a date.
I tried to make it non editable using `'readonly'` but it was not working, then I tried the following `js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.date').each(function(){
    var pickr = $(this).pickadate({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 5, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
      editable: true
    });

    $(this).click(function(){
        pickr.pickadate('open');
    });
  })

  $('select').material_select();
});
```

It is also not working. I am able to select date, then easily edit it by clicking the box. Even i can enter any value.

i also have one more `js` which set `maxdate` and `mindate` for datepciker :

```
$(function () {
  $('#datepicker,#datepicker1,#datepicker2,#datepicker3')
    .datepicker({ maxDate: '+1m', minDate: 0 });
});
```

`datepicker3` is the only datepicker in this page

So how can i make the datepicker readonly as well as required? ie, once it is selected it cannot be edited manually other than selecting a newdate using datepicker.

Comment: Where is a question in this?

Comment: yea..i have updated

Comment: It is a standard input - does the `disabled` attribute not work?

Comment: i tried 'disabled'Then it is no even showing 'required' when i click submit,it gets submitted

Comment: Set `editble` to false in the `pickadate()` config on `blur`.

Comment: how it can be done?

Comment: Well, I just read the docs - you cannot set editable to false or readOnly to true AND use required. But don't take my word for it: http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#html5-attributes

Comment: i dont have a pickdate.js file...instead i am having jquery js. so will this work?